# Improperly placed closed parenthesis in scheme function

Tags: scheme, racket, curly-braces

I have the following scheme function:

```
(define get-ivars
  (λ (ivars num)
    (cond ((null? ivars) '())
          (else
           (append (list (car ivars) `(nth args ,num)) (list (get-ivars (cdr ivars) (+ num 1))))))))
```

That returns the following in a specific instance:

```
(x (nth args 1) (y (nth args 2) ()))
```

The problem is, I need it to return:

```
((x (nth args1)) (y (nth args 2)) ())
```

-the two closing parenthesis at the end should be after the (nth statements.

How would I go about getting this to work properly?

get-ivars caller:

```
(define gen-classes
  (λ (classes)
    (cond ((null? classes) '())
          (else
           (let* ((class (car classes)))
             (eval
              `(define ,(cadr class)
                 (λ (args)
                   (let (
                          ,(get-ivars (cdr (cadddr class)) 1)
                          )
                     (eval
                      (let* ,(cdar (cddddr class))
                        (λ (method . args)
                          ,(get-methods (cdadr (cddddr class)))
     ))))))))))))
```

Comment: A bit unrelated, but it'd help if you can collapse the `(define get-ivars (λ (ivars num) ...))` into `(define (get-ivars ivars num) ...)`, since that's slightly easier to read. Also, you don't really need `cond` here -- an `if` would work just as well. :)

Comment: Wait, how can you possibly return `(x (nth args1)) (y (nth args 2)) ()`? That's returning multiple values! Did you mean to return `((x (nth args1)) (y (nth args 2)) ())` instead?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, that's what I meant. My bad! Edited in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second `(list ...)` in your `else` clause is what's screwing you up. It's nesting each successive call deeper and deeper. The recursion will naturally create the list; you don't need to wrap it again.

Try:

```
(define get-ivars
  (λ (ivars num)
    (if (null? ivars) '()
      (cons (list (car ivars) `(nth args ,num)) 
            (get-ivars (cdr ivars) (+ num 1))))))
```

Regarding the `get-ivars` caller code, the parentheses surrounding the unquoted call to `get-ivars` are what's giving you the trouble you mention in the comments. With them, this code:

```
`(define ClassName
   (lambda (args)
     (let (,(get-ivars '(iVar1 iVar2 iVar3) 1))
       ;; your method-getting code
       )))
```

Gives you this:

```
(define ClassName
  (lambda (args)
    (let (((iVar1 (nth args 1))
           (iVar2 (nth args 2))
           (iVar3 (nth args 3))))
      ;; method-getting code
     )))
```

Which, as you can see, gives you an extra set of parentheses around the assignments in the let.

So you want to do this:

```
`(define ClassName
   (lambda (args)
     (let ,(get-ivars '(iVar1 iVar2 iVar3) 1)
        ;; your method-getting code
      )))
```

`get-ivars` is returning a list of lists, which is exactly what you want for the assignments in the `let`, so you don't need to wrap or (as I had it earlier) splice it. Just use the unquote on its own, and the result is:

```
(define ClassName
  (lambda (args)
    (let ((iVar1 (nth args 1))
          (iVar2 (nth args 2))
          (iVar3 (nth args 3)))
      ;; method-getting code
     )))
```

Which should do the trick.

Incidentally, I found it helpful to leave off the `eval` when I was playing around with this; one can then visually inspect the result to make sure its syntax is okay.

Comment: I believe the `cons` here screws things up (take a look at my answer) -- he *does* want the `nil` at the end to stay, and he doesn't want things to get appended together. But I could be wrong too... I haven't tested either.

Comment: Well, this returns what I want, but maybe I wasn't sure what I wanted. I'm passing the value to a (let ...), but the let spits out "bad syntax (not an identifier) in: (x (nth args 1))". The function you provided returns: ((x (nth args 1)) (y (nth args 2)))

Comment: @Mehrdad: Oh, I see. You're quite right. I hadn't registered that -- it seems strange to want to keep the `'()`. I've just tested both of our functions and they work, the only difference being the `'()` at the end.

Comment: I'd like to note, if I put the **expected** output: `(x (nth args 1)) (y (nth args 2))`, in place of the call to `get-ivars`, the code works fine.

Comment: This may be veering into another question. . .I assume you have `args` defined somewhere? EDIT: Oh, yes, you said that.

Comment: This is all being eval'd and quoted, to dynamically create a function; args will be the arguments of this created function.

Secondly, calling `(car (get-ivars ...))` properly set's x, so it seems let is assuming `(x (nth args 1)) (y (nth args 2)))` is a single expression, which it is, but I'd want it treated as two separate expressions for let's sake.

Comment: Geez, I can feel my rusty Scheme gears creaking. You might need to post some of the enclosing code. Can you do a splice? <code>`(let ,@(get-ivars ivar-list 0))</code> The `let` is taking the list you get from `get-ivars` as a single expression, exactly. I'm going to edit my answer to show what it looks like literally; it's an invalid let expression.

Comment: I was wrong in my last comment. The `let` expression is valid. I think there were other problems with the integration of the result into the `let`, and I've added to my answer. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Where should the closing parenthesis before `,@` go?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which closing parentheses you mean. The only change I made was this: `(let @(,(get-ivars` to this: `(let (,@(get-ivars`

Comment: I feel like I'm going crazy; when I copy-pasted your code last night, I swear I got a splice operator `@`, but now I see that it isn't there. I have updated my answer one last time to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can't believe after all that it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think this would work:

```
(define (get-ivars ivars num)
    (if (null? ivars)
    '()
    (list (list (car ivars) `(nth args ,num))
          (get-ivars (cdr ivars) (1+ num)))))
```